# While editing the customer in backend throws exception in magento 2

Tags: customer, grid, admin-panel, magento2.2.6, edit

I am trying to edit the customer in backend, while clicking edit it thows the below exception

[image]

Comment: Check this links if you can help.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12660

Comment: Refer this links as well.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13213